# Create a bitmap from drawable resource filepath

Tags: android, image, list, bitmap, drawable

I would like to create an image chooser from my drawable resources. I think I have found an "easy" way to do this. I was going to create a listview that displays the drawables , and the user would be able to pick one. I would then pass back , the path to this drawable resource, the paths would be hard-coded in. I then would set a bitmap to this drawable path.  I was trying to do a simple test of this with just hard coded values, (no listview yet) but I do not get a visible bitmap back. I think it "works" , but maybe the bitmap is to small or not set to visible?

```
bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/gds2/res/drawable-hdpi/feel_like_a_sir.png");

foreground_imageview.setImageBitmap(bm2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to load your drawable in this way

```
bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.feel_like_a_sir);
foreground_imageview.setImageBitmap(bm2);
```